# Problema no SigIn do google ao re-logar no Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google

Estou com um pequeno problema ao logar no *Firebase* utilizando o *Google SigIn*. 
A questão é que estou conseguindo logar com esse método, mas quando ocorre algum problema após selecionar alguma conta (figura abaixo) eu não consigo mais escolher outra conta para tentar logar novamente, ele insiste na mesma conta, mas por não autenticar fica inviável prosseguir.

A ideia que quero é que, ao gerar o erro, ele me permita escolher outra conta, ou que ele me mostre esse popup novamente.

Não quero colocar outro método de login por enquanto.

Segue o código que estou utilizando:

```
package com.nome_do_pacote.login;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nome_do_pacote.R;
import com.nome_do_pacote.data_manager.LibraryIO;
import com.nome_do_pacote.listener_firebase.CustomValueEventListener;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private SignInButton signInButton;
    public static final int SIGN_IN_CODE = 777;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tela_login_in);

        //Adicionando uma Toolbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.signInButton);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
        signInButton.setColorScheme(SignInButton.COLOR_DARK);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(intent, SIGN_IN_CODE);
            }
        });

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    downloadFirebase();
                    goMainScreen();
                }
            }
        };
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {   }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_CODE) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(result.getSignInAccount());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.not_log_in, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //É esse toast que aparece quando ocorre o problema.
        }
    }



    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        signInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(signInAccount.getIdToken(), null);
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                signInButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.not_firebase_auth, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void goMainScreen() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainLogin.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (firebaseAuthListener != null) {
            firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_contato, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_contato:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("email"));
                String[] email = {getResources().getString(R.string.mEmail)};
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, email);
                intent.setType("menssage/rfc822");
                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.selecion_email)));

                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.nao_existe_email_instalado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    DatabaseReference mDataBase = LibraryIO.getFirebaseRef().child("horarios");
    private CustomValueEventListener customValueEventListener;

    private void downloadFirebase(){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.baixandolistasdehorarios, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        customValueEventListener = new CustomValueEventListener(Login.this);
        mDataBase.addValueEventListener(customValueEventListener);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.tudo_pronto, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (customValueEventListener != null) {
            mDataBase.removeEventListener(customValueEventListener);
        }
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por algum motivo, ele está fazendo cache da solução. O que pode fazer é, quando der erro, forçar o signout desta forma (coloca abaixo do toast):

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
```

Acredito que quando apertar para fazer o login novamente, ele vai mostrar a seleção. Lembrando que se o usuário sair do aplicativo (se o seu tiver uma opção de sair), ela também deve ser chamada.